# Nested documents are missing while trying to write into Mongo Database

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to add the transaction details in the nested transaction object in Mongo DB when the batch job runs for some user with higher transaction some of the transaction details are missing but in logs i am not seeing any concurrency error what i understood from analysis is when multiple threads try to updated the same nested document the details being over ridden by another thread. Below is the code i am using to write the transaction details

I am using a Pojo object to set the fields to transaction object and writing the object to nested mongo database

Transaction object contains the following details transaction_uuid, transaction_amount, transaction_source, transaction_status and transaction_timestamp

I am using below code to write it to Mongo Database

```
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = new MongoClient(connection_string).getDatabase(dbName)
            .getCollection(collectionName);

    Bson filter = and(eq("userId", userId),
                 eq("branchCode", branchCode);

    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    String transactionInstanceJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(transactionEvent);
        Document transactionInstanceDocument = Document.parse(transactionInstanceJson);
        UpdateResult queryStatus = collection.updateOne(filter, 
                     Updates.addToSet("transactionEvent",transactionInstanceDocument ));
```

Please help with some suggestion i don't want to go with MongoSession as it impact the performance of the code.